# Automatic retrieval of flight prices in Google Sheets using IMPORTXML function

Tags: html, google-sheets, xml-parsing

I am planning to visit South America next year with a couple of friends.  We created a Google Spreadsheet with different dates of arriving and departing airports.  The problem is that when we complied the file, it was already outdated since the prices are changing every hour/day.  I thought to create a script or an `IMPORTXML` function to automatically retrieve the data from the websites. The data would refresh every time I open the file.  `IMPORTXML` might work but I was not able to configure it properly. I am assigning a cell to this function:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.klm.com/travel/de_en/apps/ebt/calendar.htm?application=EBT7&country=DE&language=en&barsEnabled=true&fixedDatesOnly=false&canModify=ORIGIN%2CDESTINATION%2CTRAVELDATES%2CPAX%2CCABINCLASS%2CURL&trip=MAD:A:20200701%3ERIO:C-RIO:C:20200719%3EMAD:A&numberOfAdults=1&numberOfYoungAdults=&numberOfChildren=&numberOfInfants=&cabinClass=ECONOMY&outboundMonth=", "//*[@id=""brandedFaresWidgetContainer""]/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/ul/li[1]/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/button/span")
```

I am only getting N/A in the cell. I think this is because the `IMPORTXML` function has an internal timeout which expires before the webpage ([link](https://www.klm.com/travel/de_en/apps/ebt/calendar.htm?application=EBT7&country=DE&language=en&barsEnabled=true&fixedDatesOnly=false&canModify=ORIGIN%2CDESTINATION%2CTRAVELDATES%2CPAX%2CCABINCLASS%2CURL&trip=MAD:A:20200701%3ERIO:C-RIO:C:20200719%3EMAD:A&numberOfAdults=1&numberOfYoungAdults=&numberOfChildren=&numberOfInfants=&cabinClass=ECONOMY&outboundMonth=)) is loaded so it cannot really retrieve the element. The problem is that I didn't find a way to increase the timeout of this function. For the `XPATH` I am using the built-in copy XPATH location in Google Chrome Developer Tools

How can I retrieve this price from the Internet and populate it into a Google Spreadsheet cell?

Answer (score 2):

unfortunately, you will need to find a different source website for your data. this one uses JavaScript and Google Sheets does not support imports of JS elements. you can test this simply by disabling JS for a given site and only what's left can be imported. in your case it's:

[image: 0]

Comment: Any other idea, how I can retrieve this data apart of `IMPORTXML`, which apparently I can't use in this case.

Comment: it's not `IMPORTXML`-specific issue. it applies for import formula variants. eg its limitation of GS. your only option is to find some similar site with same data

Comment: what if I create some script in the script editor. I am just saying it because I have tried the Ryanair website and there they are also using Javascript, which is complicating the task.

Comment: its a dead end with the script too. but I heard a rumor that MS Excel is able to scrape JS via VBA

Comment: what if I use some web scraper to fetch the javascript data, I mean to convert the webpage with the javascript to a static page, upload the page to one VM I own and use `IMPORTXML` to populate the Google Sheets?